# Product still showing out of stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, inventory, stock

Previously in my Magento store, I had set the **Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock** in the **inventory** to **5** under **system->configuration->catalog->inventory** so that if the quantity of the products reaches to **5 or below** it should show as **out of stock** and it was working properly. Now I want the quantity to be displayed according to the exact number and hence I changed the value of **Qty for Item's Status** to Become Out of Stock from **5 to 0**. But even after changing the products are still showing out of stock when the count reaches 5. I have reindexed all the data and I have even cleared the cache after changing the value. Kindly let me know what should I do to **enable the products to show in stock even if the count reaches 5 or below**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: The value could be overwritten by explicit store view config or per product did you check that?

Comment: as per @rayphi please check the config.
Also reindex after updating it.